# Butterknife not loading layout after adapter has been modified

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, butterknife

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

My Adapter looks like this:

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<String> sourceData;

    public TestAdapter(List<String> sourceData) {
        this.sourceData = sourceData;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spanitem_goods, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String item = sourceData.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sourceData.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.spanitem_imageView)
        ImageView imageView;
        @BindView(R.id.spanitem_textView)
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my Activity I am transacting different Fragments which have all the same above adapter. It works fine with swapping them in and out, but as soon as I call this on adapter

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
```

and swap the fragments in and out again, it does not load any layout anymore. Just a blank page and this only happens when I call the above method.

My abstract `BaseFragment` has this in `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "... onCreateView() called");
    View v = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResourceId(), container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
    Log.d(TAG, "... onDestroyView() called");
}
```

Comment: Are all your fragments sharing the same instance of the `TestAdapter` or are they only using multiple instances of the same class?

Comment: @NitroNbg They all have their own instance

Comment: I think that `adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);` could be the red herring here (i.e. it's not the underlying bug) , could you post the entire method in which you execute this call?

Comment: @NitroNbg It's basically a one liner where I get some Strings from a socket and insert it into the arraylist `sourceData` and notify the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the issue. Seems pretty unrelated to the entry question, but I might help someone else.

I was using the `Observer` pattern and had the `update` method in a non-ui thread running. Seems like that was the problem, since the `RecyclerView` never got updated unless I scrolled manually.

```
 @Override
    public void update(final String epc) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sourceData.add(epc);
                notifyDataSourceChanged(sourceData.size() - 1);
            }
        });

    }
```